# How to insert checked values from checkbox in mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql, database, while-loop, radio-button

There are many Subject in my database. I called them in a form in checkbox. When some checkbox checked, those value will go on my database in "select_subject" table in subject column. And when checked a radio button for course name, its value will go in "course" column. My mysql query and chackbox code was:

```
                <?php
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vhsubject WHERE lid= 2");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                echo "<input type='checkbox'  name='vhsubject[]' value=".$row['subject_name'].">" .$row['subject_name']."<br />";
                } 
                ?>
```

After checked and submit, my query was

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['form'])) {
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO select_subject (subject, course) VALUES ('$_POST[vhsubject]', '$_POST[course_radio]')";
    $insert = mysql_query ($query2) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($insert){
            echo "Your registration is complete";
        }
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me;

Comment: If possible, give me full code please

Comment: Use Implode Function

Answer (score 0):

**Use Implode Function:**

You can not store value in the form of an array in mysql, so first convert array into string by using implode function.

here is the example:

```
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a1">Used e-mail<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a2">Used instant messenger & chat room<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a3">Made a purchase for personal use<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a4">Downloaded/Played a video game<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a5">Obtained news/information/current events<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a6">Looked for employment (Used classified listings)<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a7">Looked for recipes<br>
<input name="q1[]" type="checkbox" value="a8">Downloaded a movie<br>
```

and now use implode function:

```
<?php
        $q1=implode(',', $_POST['q1']);
?>
```